# Automatic Convert Virtual Address to Memory Address?

Tags: assembly, x86

i am using c# to read a exe file and inject a code to display a message box when the exe run so the code i am using is the following :

```
6A 00               //push 0
68 OXxxxx          //push Address of Message Title
68 OXxxxx          //push Address of Message Body
6A 00              //push 0
FF 15 OXxxxx      //Call Address of User32.MessageBoxA 
E9 OXxxxx          // jmp to old entry point
```

all addresses i am using are virtual addresses but  the new exe cant run , i think the addresses should translate to memory address (by windows loader) but how i can do that ??.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual addresses are memory addresses.
But if .exe has relocation table, it can be relocated to new base address, and if your `push` and `call` instructions hasn't entries in relocation table, it will be broken.

Also I'm not sure that your code is right, because I don't see where are strings used in your code.

To ensure that issue is missing entries in relocation table, try the following position-independent code:

```
6A 00          // push 0
6A 00          // push 0
E8 04 00 00 00 // call $+5+4
31 32 33 00    // '123', 0
6A 00          // push 0
68 XX XX XX XX // push user32.MessageBoxA address, it's the same in all processes
C3             // retn
E9 XX XX XX XX // jmp OEP
```

**Upd:** as [ruslik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395626/ruslik) noted, if we patch a file, we don't know the *user32.MessageBoxA* address, so we should find it in another way.

If we know address of its IAT entry, we should replace `FF 15 (__imp_MessageBoxA)` to something base independent:

```
     E8 00 00 00 00  // call base:
base:
     58              // pop eax
     05 XX XX XX XX  // add eax, __imp_MessageBoxA - base
     FF 10           // call dword ptr [eax]
```

Comment: 2 questions :
1 - what is 
(E8 04 00 00 00 // call $+5+4
 31 32 33 00    // '123', 0
 6A 00          // push 0)
2 - how to add entries for push and call instructions in relocation table

Comment: @radi 1. - it's some assembly code. You should learn it, before trying to infect PE. 2. - read PE format specs.

Comment: Small correction: The `call` doesn't need a relocation entry, what it needs to do is refer to the import table.

Comment: @Fabian Giesen there is `call dword ptr [mem32]` (opcode FF 15)

Comment: I think there's little missunderstanding. Code in your example is for in-memory patching while OP asked about in-file patching. Where will he get the address of `MessageBoxA`? Please update it to use IAT.